# (DJANGO) retrieving data from html form using GET/POST

Tags: html, django

This is part of the CS50W courseware Project 1. I have tried to retrieve a user input from a form using a get method. However, the `search_query` variable in views.py does not have any input. I then changed the get methods to post methods and it worked. Why is that so?

`layout.html` (GET method)

```html
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="GET">
    <input type="search" name="search_query" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
</form>
```

`views.py` (GET method)

```py
def search(request):
    search_query = request.GET['search_query']
    if search_query in util.list_entries():
        return redirect('entry_page', title=search_query)
    for entry in util.list_entries():
        if search_query in entry:
            return redirect('search_results')
```

`layout.html` (POST method)

```html
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="search" name="search_query" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
</form>
```

`views.py` (POST method)

```py
def search(request):
    search_query = request.POST['search_query']
    if search_query in util.list_entries():
        return redirect('entry_page', title=search_query)
    for entry in util.list_entries():
        if search_query in entry:
            return redirect('search_results')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to differences in the nature of http requests. In POST requests we send the data separately, but in GET requests we have to put them in the url. You probably expect form to do this for you, but it does not! This means that this form will not put the parameters in the url in GET mode.

Comment: So does that mean that as long as there is the `action` attribute within `form`, the request method always have to be POST?

Comment: In the forms we are sending data to the server and we use POST to send the data!